# add_meta_box mixed up custom query post_id with global post_id

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created two groups of metaboxes (metabox1 and metabox2) within a CPT. In one of them (metabox2) I run a custom query to retrieve a bunch of post ids to show them in a select fild. 
The problem arise when the other metabox (metabox1) picks up the one of the post_id retrieved from the custom query instead of the post_id in the global environment, so eventually this metabox1 cannot retrieve the data from the db because the post_id is wrong.

This the custom query and I've put different reset postdate, but they don't seem to work:

````
  $podcasts = [];

  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'desc',
                    'post_type' => 'podcast',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true );

  $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if($my_query->have_posts()):
    while($my_query->have_posts()):
      $my_query->the_post();
      $podcasts[] = [get_the_ID(),get_the_title()];
    endwhile;

  endif;
  $my_query->reset_postdata();
 wp_reset_postdata();
  // wp_reset_query();
  return $podcasts;
}```
````

Comment: use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to get posts instead of WP_Query

Comment: I think this is the solution I was looking for : using a $temp_post variable
[link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/using-the-loop-inside-admin/21982#21982)